# ReactVr - document is not defined

Tags: react-360

I'm trying to access the document in a react vr app.  The app was created using the react-vr-cli.  However, when I try to access the page I get the following error.

```
document is not defined
```

Comment: This is strange. Can you post your poject somewhere?

Comment: sorry for the late reply.  I found out whats wrong.  the document was in a self invoking function and for some reason the scope of the function wasn't the window, its DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope.

Comment: Hi, I checked again, the problem wasn't self invoking function.  If I import a script, the script is ran in DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope instead of window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The React VR instance is run inside a web worker, that's why you're getting [`DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope) instead of `window` and why there's no global `document`.

This is just how React VR works and it's why there's a [`react-vr-web`](https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/tree/master/ReactVR) package that's in charge of communicating with the VR instance via `postMessage`.

Unfortunately web workers only have access to a subset of the features present on in the browser on the global scope. 
For some you can find workarounds in React VR like [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/asyncstorage.html) instead of `localStorage`. For everything else you'll have to figure out a way of communicating outside the web worker via [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) and with a listener on [`onmessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/onmessage).

Another way of sending stuff from `window` to the VR instance is to implement a native module as a bridge between the two. You can find more info in 
[Persistent bridge between a React VR component and native module code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394508/persistent-bridge-between-a-react-vr-component-and-native-module-code).