# Creating 2D scene in ReactVR

Tags: javascript, virtual-reality, react-360

Can I create a 2D scene in ReactVR? I mean displaying elements on a screen like in normal React, for example, classical web menu which will be always displayed in the same place on screen. Or something like HUD in 3D games.

Comment: Your React VR app will be rendered inside a canvas element on the page so you could overlay other HTML elements on top of it using CSS to create a HUD.
This HUD could then be updated by setting up a bridge between the VR web worker and the main page, one way to do is is described here https://stackoverflow.com/q/44394508/1333383

Comment: You can also check out the official DOM Overlay approach here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/tree/a2f615b22b3f8845e583b62115a6807d8a4a663b/Examples/DomOverlaySample

Keep in mind - these elements will not appear in VR.

Answer (score 1):

More context on what you are trying to achieve or what platforms you are targeting would help, but here are a few guidelines:

**IN VR**

You generally don't want to have permanent overlays or components that move along with the user. This tends to break immersion unless very carefully designed and properly implemented. You can still render 2D elements using the built-in `Text`, `Image`, and `View` components, but you have to be smart about interactions. A common alternative to this approach is fading in a menu/HUD whenever the user looks in a particular direction, e.g. when looking at the ground.

Either way, you will want to take a look at [VrHeadModel](https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/blob/master/Libraries/Utilities/VrHeadModel.js) and the APIs it exposes to query user's Yaw/Pitch/Roll or how to listen for head rotation events.

**On WEB & Mobile**

For these platforms, you can implement menus/HUDs using the [DOM Overlay](https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/tree/master/Examples/DomOverlaySample) concept, which renders a traditional 2D surface on top of the 360 scene.

The linked sample shows how to implement what you need in 2D, using plain React, html, css, etc. In this case, it renders a simple overlay with text on it, but you can use it to implement persistent overlays, menus or whatever UI you believe is better consumed in 2D instead of within the 360 scene.